# OpenDocument manipulation in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, opendocument

I'm writing a program in Common Lisp that needs to:

1. Load values from several ODS spreadsheets,
2. process them
3. and finally generate reports in ODS and ODT formats.

The only actual library I've found so far is [ODS4CL](http://www.cliki.net/ODS4CL), but it doesn't support any styles at the moment.

How can I write my program with minimal efforts (without writing a general-purpose OpenDocument manipulation library)?

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  This is a _useful_ question, but not a great fit for Stack Overflow.  You might have a look on the CLiki, though…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've edited the question according to my current understanding of SO rules. Could you tell me if it really fits now, please? And, if still not, what's wrong about it?

Comment: It's certainly a bit better, but it's still pretty broad ("There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.")  I think you've added some of that detail, and you're getting closer.  I just took a look at ODS4CL, and while I see some things about styles in there (`make-styles-file`), the library as a whole looks a bit brittle (e.g., rather than generating XML using an XML library, it outputs many static strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen several packages being able to [make](http://www.cliki.net/data%20formats) or [convert](https://github.com/thomp/otl-opendocument) stuff to OpenDocument but not read. Pehaps it's because you just need to [unzip](http://quickdocs.org/zip/) and [parse xml](http://quickdocs.org/search?q=XML) to actually read read it.

Comment: Most likely it's the only option (including making a new library or binding to some well-known one via FFI).